# pip install PyAudio: error: command 'cl.exe' failed: No such file or directory

Tags: python, cmd, voice-recognition, pyaudio

I am trying to install PyAudio on windows 10 but i am getting the following error. first it has given the error to install Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools so i installed successfully. But now it showing following. Thanks

```
 ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: 'c:\users\nadeem\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\NADEEM\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-g79_tntp\\PyAudio\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\NADEEM\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-g79_tntp\\PyAudio\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\NADEEM\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-_8egf72w\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile
     cwd: C:\Users\NADEEM\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-g79_tntp\PyAudio\
Complete output (13 lines):
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib.win32-3.8
copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8
running build_ext
building '_portaudio' extension
creating build\temp.win32-3.8
creating build\temp.win32-3.8\Release
creating build\temp.win32-3.8\Release\src
cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Ic:\users\nadeem\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\include -Ic:\users\nadeem\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\include /Tcsrc/_portaudiomodule.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.8\Release\src/_portaudiomodule.obj
error: command 'cl.exe' failed: No such file or directory
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\nadeem\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\NADEEM\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-g79_tntp\\PyAudio\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\NADEEM\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-g79_tntp\\PyAudio\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\NADEEM\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-_8egf72w\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 2):

The pip install is trying to download and compile the library. Getting the Windows compilers are easier now, but can be a pain. https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers

Years ago when the compilers were a true pain to get Christoph Gohlke compiled and distributed the libraries for windows.

https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio

Download the .whl file for your python version and tell pip to install that file.

```
 pip install ~/Downloads/PyAudio‑0.2.11‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl
```